# RIOT.JS: Showing an element depending on input value

Tags: riot.js

I would like to do something like this:

```
<input type="text" value={ value1 } >
<input if={ value1 != ''} type="text">
```

So, adding to DOM the second input when the first input has any value different than empty. I know 2-way data binding is not supported by Riot.js

I have tried to do the following:

```
<input ref="first" type="text" >
<input if={ this.refs.first.value != '' } type="text">
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, Riot does not do 2-way data binding for reasons I'll leave to the reader to research. It's fascinating stuff, but in my opinion, most web development can be made drastically simpler by following a few simple patterns. Riot is great for this reason. Simply put, the tag is just markup with event listeners that can update the tag.

```
<my-tag>
  <input name='username' type='text' onKeyup={ checkVal } value={ opts.val }>
  <input if={ usernameEntered } name='password' type='password'>

  <script>
    this.checkVal = (event) => {
      this.usernameEntered = event.target.value !== ''
      // this.update() is implicitly called in event listeners
    }
  </script>
</my-tag>
```

In your case (I don't know your exact use case), you may want to populate the first input element with a value passed into the tag (`opts.val`). Then we can assign some variable (`usernameEntered`) in an event listener (`checkVal`) and `update` the tag.

See [Riot JS Guide](http://riotjs.com/guide/) for more detailed examples